# Кнопка обратного звонка

Tags: php

есть кнопка обратного звонка. После отправки запроса я хочу чтобы текст показывался не в новом окне а в том же где я заполнял поля. Помогите сделать http://nailart-studio.com/callback/

номер телефона: 10 цыфр

Answer (score 1):

Можете сделать обработку форму на странице http://nailart-studio.com/callback/ и проверять существование переменной $_POST и тогда выводить Ваше сообщение

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте AJAX запрос, и результат выводите в блок div, который уместите в своем окне. Пример:

```
 $('#authSubmit').click(function () {

        var field1 = $("#field1").val();
        var field2 = $("#field2").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/obrabotchikFormi.php",
            data: {"field1": field1, "field2": field2},
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $("#result").empty();
                $("#result").append(html);
                $("#result").stop();
                $("#result").fadeOut(800);
                $("#result").fadeIn(800);

            }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="result"></div> // результат
```